# Change status, Using javascript controller, and calling the auto change status from the database

Tags: javascript, database, controller, momentjs

Good Morning.

Maybe someone can help with this logic and code, I have written a controller where it calls the database settings and then tries to find a ticket that is older than 1 month, if that ticket is older than a month, it should auto change the status from " in progress with customer " to " customer input required " all it has to do is see if that ticket is older than 1 month and then change its status value. please see code snipplets below and screenshots.

thanks in advance

Comment: images are not displaying for me. Can you explain in text what is the issue on what you have done so far? At  which step is it not behaving the way you want?

Comment: Okay, let me try :). 

what I am trying  to is change one status from status_id 11 to status_id 6 if the status_id is older than 30 days/ 1 month automatically, so it looks at a ticket_status_id 11 and sees if its last_modified date is older than 30 days it should then auto change the status to ticket_status 6 if that makes sense ?

so it looks at the DB tables - settings and event_type. 

settings has a setting_value which = 43200 minutes(30 days)
event_type table has an event_type id which = 38 for auto change status, it then has to call those values as you can see in the code above